# Google spreadsheets.create with merged cells

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Create google spreadsheets api test on: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "merges": [
        {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 12,
          "endRowIndex": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So i tried using google spreadsheets create with merged cells but it returned an error of:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid sheets[0].merges[0]: No grid with id: 0",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Anyone know where I got it wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this request body? It sets `sheetId` for properties.

```
{
  "sheets": 
  [
    {
      "merges": 
      [
        {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 12,
          "endRowIndex": 3
        }
      ],
      "properties": 
      {
        "sheetId": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Reference :

- [SheetProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SheetProperties)

Comment: @Klaudius Raymond Natio I'm glad your issue was solved.